# Multiple interfaces match the same subnet - how to fix this?

Tags: wireless-access-point, raspbian, dhcp-server

I have a raspberry pi 2 with a lan interface (eth0) and wan interface (wlan0)- usb wifi adapter. My OS is raspbian. I want to use my raspberry as a wifi AP. So, it is necessary to have a ics-dhcp-server running on my wlan0.

I want to have a shared local network, so PCs and wi-fi clients can see each other. So:

- PC's are connected to router's (192.168.254.4) lan with wired
  connection and they have static ip in range 192.168.254.1 -
  192.168.254.99 (except 192.168.254.4). The Raspberry Pi LAN ip is 192.168.254.97.
- Wi-FI clients are connected to my raspberry pi and should have ip in
  range of 192.168.254.201 - 192.168.254.250. The Raspberry Pi wlan ip
  is 192.168.254.200.

An internet goes from lan to wlan using MASQERADE.

My configs are:

cat **/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**:

```
subnet 192.168.254.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
interface wlan0;
    range 192.168.254.201 192.168.254.250;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.254.255;
        option routers 192.168.254.200;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option domain-name "local";
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 64.6.64.6, 64.6.65.6;
host wlan0 {
fixed-address 192.168.254.200;
}
}
```

cat **/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**:

```
INTERFACESv4="wlan0"
```

cat **/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.254.201,192.168.254.250,255.255.255.0,24h
```

cat **/etc/dhcpcd.conf**

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.254.97
static routers=192.168.254.4
# 192.168.254.4 
static domain_name_servers=192.168.254.4
static domain_search=

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.254.200/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
static routers=
static domain_name_servers=
static domain_search=
```

With this configs i get errors when trying to start isc-dhcp-server:

```
Multiple interfaces match the same subnet: eth0 wlan0
 Multiple interfaces match the same shared network: eth0 wlan0
 Can't bind to dhcp address: Address already in use
```

Where is the mistake in my configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first mistake is having multiple interfaces in the same subnet. The second mistake is that **you're *heavily* mixing up what a router does** (masquerading, serving DHCP) **and what an access point does** (giving access to the same subnet). In a sense, they actually do opposite things.

- A router connects two *whole* networks. It does not connect two halves of the same network – after all, if a host is "is in the same subnet", that *literally* means that it's accessible without going through a router.

  So if you want to use the Raspberry Pi as a router (with MASQUERADE or without), then the two interfaces have to use different network numbers – it can't be the same 192.168.254.0/24 on both sides.

  But you said "I want to have a shared local network", so you *don't* actually want to use your Raspberry Pi as a router – you want to use it as an access point.
- An access point is *not* a router, it's a bridge. An access point **does not need to serve DHCP,** because it simply forwards the DHCP requests to the previous router that you already have. It also doesn't need to 'MASQUERADE' anything, because it only deals with a single network anyway.

  If you want both Wi-Fi and Ethernet to be in a single subnet for an AP, they have to be explicitly *bridged* together. Once bridged, eth0 and wlan0 will stop having IP addresses of their own – only the bridge itself, "br0", will need an address.

  (An access point *can* serve DHCP – but only if your main router doesn't. Remember, you wanted a single shared network, and there needs to be *only one* DHCP server across the entire network.)

So if you want to set up an AP, there are existing articles about "raspbian bridge", specifically **https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md** will also work on Raspbian.

(But **not** https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=132674 – that's high up in Google results, but it actually tells you how to set up a *router*, not a bridge. Ignore that page.)

But in short, what you should do is:

1. Remove the 'MASQUERADE' firewall rule (it only applies to routers, not to bridges);
2. Remove *both* 'interface eth0' and 'interface wlan0' from your dhcpcd.conf;
3. Configure `/etc/systemd/network/br0.netdev` to create the bridge through systemd-networkd:

   ```
   [NetDev]
   Name=br0
   Kind=bridge
   ```

   Don't forget to `systemctl enable systemd-networkd`.
4. Similarly, configure systemd-networkd to set eth0 as a member of br0. (Only eth0 – hostapd itself will handle wlan0.)
5. Assign an IP address to br0, either through systemd-networkd or dhcpcd (doesn't matter).
6. Tell hostapd to put wlan0 in the bridge as well:

   ```
   interface=wlan0
   bridge=br0
   ```

   (This has to be done via hostapd because wlan0 only becomes bridgeable when it's actually switched to "access point" mode.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

I've done this steps:

1. Removed firewall rule MASQUERADE
2. Removed interface eth0 and wlan0 from **/etc/dhcpcd.conf**
3. created **/etc/systemd/network/br0.netdev** with:

   [NetDev]

   Name=br0

   Kind=bridge
4. created **/etc/systemd/network/br0-slave.network** with:

   [Match]

   Name=eth0

   [Network]

   Bridge=br0
5. created **/etc/systemd/network/br0.network** with:

   [Match]
   Name=br0

   [Network]

   Address=192.168.254.106/24

   Gateway=192.168.254.4

   DNS=192.168.254.4
6. my **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf** now is:

   interface=wlan0

   #country=RU

   bridge=br0

   driver=nl80211

   #driver=ath9k_htc

   #driver=mt7601u

   ssid=somename

   hw_mode=g

   channel=7

   wmm_enabled=0

   macaddr_acl=0

   auth_algs=1

   ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

   wpa=2

   wpa_passphrase=somepass

   wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

   wpa_pairwise=TKIP

   rsn_pairwise=CCMP

   logger_syslog=-1
7. Also i've added a "killall wpa_supplicant" in my **/etc/rc.local**, so now it is:

   rfkill unblock wifi

   killall wpa_supplicant

   exit 0

And rebooted. Now i have a working AP with internet, but when i try to connect to any server/site with my Raspberry, there is no connection (can't do apt-get install ... or ping google.com - host is unreachable). Also i can see old ip address on my eth0 (192.168.254.105) though it is commented in my /etc/dhcpcd.conf. Where else i can find my old eth0 ip address for deleting it?